# Invisible (transparent) font color with css on all major browsers

Tags: css

Is it possible to make the font (font-color) transparent while using any color like black or white? Just have the font slowly disappear, like `display:none`. Thanks

Answer (score 21):

You can use css property

```
opacity: 0;
```

and you will not be able to select the text,

or

```
color: transparent;
```

and you will have the chance to select the text.

If you want to make this slowly look at jQuery functions `.fadeOut()` http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/ or `.animate()` http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 5):

You can use RGBA colors, where the last level is alpha (transparency), e.g.:

`color:rgba(255,0,0,0.3);`

Which is red at 30% opacity. RGBA values are supported by IE9+, Firefox 3+, Chrome, Safari, and in Opera 10+.

You also have [HSLA](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/CR-css3-color-20030514/#hsla-color), e.g.:

`color: hsla(0,100%,50%,0.6);`

Again, the last value, alpha, sets the transparency