# Split text effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, typography

I am trying to mimic this look of the text split, I found the codepen.io for it but it uses SCSS and I am looking for it to be CSS only if possible. If someone could help me translate the code or make it so that is CSS, that would be great. Thanks for the help in advance.
[image]

Comment: Codepen here: https://codepen.io/alexfislegend/pen/NGaaWY?q=split+text&limit=all&type=type-pens

Comment: On CodePen, click the arrow to the right of "CSS" and click "View Compiled CSS".

Comment: [Viewing the compiled CSS on Codepen](https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/editor/using-css-preprocessors/#viewing-the-compiled-output-2)

Comment: You are required to post your markup and code here, not a codepen. [mcve]

Comment: just google "convert scss to css" and you're 90% done your task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am not going to write out all of the code for you I will suggest a method of doing it:

I suggest you make two div boxes, one for the filled in or solid text and one for the outlined text.

Then you set the `color`, `font-family` ([Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com) is a good resource), `font-size`, and `font-weight`,  to suit your needs for the first div.

On the second div again set the `font-family`, `font-size`, and `font-weight` to the same values, except set the color to [transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20048372/3998484) and add a colored [border to the text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4919231/3998484). This will simulate the sort of outlined effect in the codepen.

Oh, and to make the two divs appear on the same line look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37940553/3998484).

While this will not automatically split the text between the two texts, it is a simple way to get a similar effect to what you want.

Comment: If he doesn't supply the code then the question is off topic and shouldn't be answered at all.
[Not all questions can or should be answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Rob Oo... Thank you kind sir.